# Android: detecting if app's memory has been modified

Tags: android, memory

As you can see in the title, my question is, if an app can detect if it's memory have been modified. Eg. if a value of address `0x5DF123` changed from `(float)13.77` to `(float)1234.0`?

If so, how to do that?

Comment: Sure. Store the value in two separate variables (a second with a different address than 0x5DF123) and then compare the two variables to see if they're the same. Why would you need to do this, though? The OS will prevent another app from playing with the memory in yours, and if you can't track when you're changing a variable's value then your variable has too broad a scope.

Comment: Thanks for reply. That would work till the second address won't be edited just like the first one.